# ImportError: cannot import name 'method' from 'package' (unknown location) in python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a self-developed python package and wanted to work with it but I face problems. You can find the package [here](https://pypi.org/project/GeoMeshPy/). In the package firstly I make a class (called `vertice_modifier`) and then I have some methods to do calculations on objects of the class. After installing and importing, I cannot make objects using the existing class. I tried the following:

```
from GeoMeshPy import vertice_modifier
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'vertice_modifier' from 'GeoMeshPy' (unknown location)
```

I very much appreciate any help for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot put this is as a comment yet as I am a new user.

Have you imported everything from each of the modules in your package in your `__init__.py` file?

Also, have you physically checked your site-packages folder to check that the pakcage was installed in the right place?

Comment: Dear @Gregor Watters Härtl, I added `__init__.py` but still it is not working. When I check site packages, everything is fine. How can I call my module properly in `__init__.py`? I think this is my problem. I tried `import GeoMeshPy
__version__ = '0.0.14'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass` But it doesnot work

Comment: Hey!! I have written maybe two or three packages, and for my smallest one named "vectors" I put this in my ```__init__.py``` file: ```from vectors.vec2D import *```, next line: ```from vectors.vec3D import *``` and last line: ```from vectors.ops import *```. I.e., I import everything from each of my files (modules) within my vectors directory. Do you think this might work for you?

Comment: whoops forgot to write @Ali_d

Comment: @Ali_d actually yes, now that I look at your question again, I do think your issue is in your ```__init__.py```. ```__init__.py``` is the file which gets automatically executed when you import a package, so if you don't include anything in it you would have to refer to sub-modules within your package using the dot operator. So say your class called ```vertice_modifier``` is in a file called ```vmod.py``` within your ```GeoMeshPy``` directory, then you would have to write in a script ```GeoMeshPy.vmod.vertice_modifier()``` to access the class.

Comment: @Ali_d by doing ```from GeoMeshPy.vmod import *``` in your ```__init__.py``` file, any class imported by that statement would be available in a new Python script by the import statement you mentioned in your question

Comment: @Ali_d also I think your statement ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` ```pass``` has no effect, because ```__name__``` will never be ```__main__``` in any other python script you write

Comment: dear @Gregor Watters Härtl, I very much appreciate your help. I tried what you said. I renamed the .py file existing in the directory to vmod.py. Then I again uploaded it (https://pypi.org/project/GeoMeshPy/) but after installing this version (21) I tried the syntax `GeoMeshPy.vmod.vertice_modifier()` but it gave me the error: `AttributeError: module 'GeoMeshPy' has no attribute 'vmod'`

Comment: @ hmmm! Might it be due to a circular import? I once wrote a Gmail module, and I had a very similar error to you, and for the life of me I could not figure out what was going on, and in the end it was because I had named the file I was testing it in ```email.py``` and one of the packages that my module imported (from smtplib I think) had a file named ```email.py```, so maybe that's something you could check?

Comment: I always forget to include @Ali_d hehe

Comment: Dear @Gregor Watters Härtl
Thanks for devoting so much time to my issue. I changed the name of package in pypi repository and it works now. But the remaining issue is that now the name of package in pypi is different from the name of module which I import in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Ali_d no problem at all! Ohhh I'm really happy it works now!! Haha I don't know much about publishing packages on PyPi (although I'd like to!!) but it sounds like it's just an issue with renaming?

Comment: It works now with two names :-). Thanks a lot. Something else, you do not need to metion me by @ because when comment or reply my issue then I will get notified.

Comment: Ohh that's great news man!! Sounds like a cool project that you've created :P and cheers for letting me know about the @, I'm new here so I'm still finding my way around ;)